# Passing ArrayList to another activity modifies list

Tags: android

I'm trying to pass my custom object from `Activty` A to `Activity` B. My custom object implements `Parcelable` interface and contains `ArrayList` of another `Parcelable` objects. When I put data to the `Intent` eveything is fine, but when I get the object in `Activity` B the the `ArrayList` ist modified - contains more elements then it had in previous `Activity`. Can anybody help me?

Comment: is added more object are valid

Comment: A temporary step to identify where the issue is, Try with `Collections.unmodifiablelist()` and when something tries to modify, an exception will be thrown. That should give a place to start looking at.

Comment: Add your code please